# PHP Core Warning – yii\base\ErrorException - Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii, error-handling, yii2

After I uploaded my website to the server, I found one error which appears occasionally at the bottom of my website's home page.

And Here is the error which appears when I allow the debugging mode:

Any idea about how to solve this problem?

```
PHP Core Warning – yii\base\ErrorException

PHP Startup: XCache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
2. yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError()
$_GET = [
'r' => 'site/index',
];

$_SERVER = [
'PATH' => '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin',
'ONECOM_DOMAIN_NAME' => 'aaa.org',
'ONECOM_DOMAIN_ROOT' => '/customers/f/1/0/aaa.org/',
'PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR' => '/customers/f/1/0/aaa.org//config/conf.d.php',
'ONECOM_TMPDIR' => '/customers/f/1/0/aaa.org//tmp',
'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '0',
'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'close',
'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/basic/web/index.php',
'REQUEST_URI' => '/basic/web/index.php?r=site%2Findex',
'QUERY_STRING' => 'r=site%2Findex',
'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1',
'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1',
'REMOTE_PORT' => '43417',
'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/customers/f/1/0/aaa.org/httpd.www/basic/web/index.php',
'SERVER_ADMIN' => 'support@one.com',
'REMOTE_ADDR' => '85.182.145.82',
'SERVER_PORT' => '80',
'SERVER_ADDR' => '10.246.64.54',
'SERVER_NAME' => 'aaa.org',
'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'Apache',
'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => '',
'HTTP_X_VARNISH' => '3001546637',
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' => '85.182.145.82',
'HTTP_X_ONECOM_FORWARDED_PROTO' => 'http',
'HTTP_X_ONECOM_FORWARDED_IP' => '85.182.145.82',
'HTTP_COOKIE' => '_csrf=e7f478f7d6f77251f8f671cacdf107b7452851591bfd4f69530abf911b6bb569s%3A32%3A%22g2OYEa3GXCqowo7WrBxBsI04in_U63Jl%22%3B',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36',
'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => 'max-age=0',
'HTTP_HOST' => 'aaa.org',
'WEBC_USER_DOMAIN_NAME' => 'aaa.org',
'DOMAIN_NAME' => 'aaa.org',
'WEBC_USER_DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/customers/f/1/0/aaa.org/httpd.www',
'ONECOM_DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/customers/f/1/0/aaa.org/httpd.www',
'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/customers/f/1/0/aaa.org/httpd.www',
'ONECOM_CLIENT_IP' => '85.182.145.82',
'FCGI_ROLE' => 'RESPONDER',
'PHP_SELF' => '/basic/web/index.php',
'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1424618360.1619689464569091796875,
'REQUEST_TIME' => 1424618360,
];

$_COOKIE = [
'_csrf' => 'e7f478f7d6f77251f8f671cacdf107b7452851591bfd4f69530abf911b6bb569s:32:"g2OYEa3GXCqowo7WrBxBsI04in_U63Jl";',
];
```

Comment: If you're on shared hosting you would need to see if XCache is something they support. If not you'd either need to disable it or find an alternative that would work with your hosting.

Comment: Ahmed, please copy the error message as text into the question. Your screenshots might be gone soon after you solved this. But others might run into the same issue. If the error is in text form, they might find the answer.

Comment: @Alex i will ask if they support XCache or not, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting the shared hosting customer support many times we finally solved the problem by doing the following:

- They disabled the xcache for my website
- I used PHP 5.5 for developing the website but i used PHP 5.6 in my shared host website configurations. so, I had to return it back to PHP 5.5
- I have to disable the "varnish cache" by adding this line of code to my .htaccess

  ```
   Header add "disablevcache" "true"
  ```